# GKTurnBasedMatch how to accept a new match invitation

Tags: ios, swift, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

What is the correct way to programmatically accept a match invitation with GameKit's standard user interface?

I am seeing an *expectedState="Invited" foundState="Active"* exception

```
Optional(Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=22 
"The requested operation could not be completed because the specified participant is invalid." 
UserInfo={GKServerStatusCode=5097, 
NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation could not be completed because the specified participant is invalid., 
NSUnderlyingError=0x14fa2cf70 {
Error Domain=GKServerErrorDomain Code=5097 "status = 5097, 
Unexpected slot state expectedState="Invited" foundState="Active"
```

The exception occurs under the following scenario:
Player 1 - Creates a new match with player 2
Player 1 - Makes the first move
Player 2 - Attempts to load data from the turn based match & accept the match invitation.

I am using iOs' standard user interface for match making. `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController`

**Requesting a new match**

```
let matchRequest = GKMatchRequest()
matchRequest.minPlayers = 2
matchRequest.maxPlayers = 2
matchRequest.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2
matchRequest.inviteMessage = "Play BoxTheDots with me"
matchRequest.recipientResponseHandler = self.matchMaker?.recipientResponse

let matchView = GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: matchRequest)
self.presentViewController(matchView, animated: true, completion: nil)
matchView.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self.matchMaker?.matchViewController
```

I am accepting the match invitation programmatically, which is causing and printing the error.

The code flow starts from the [GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate didFindMatch method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate_Ref/)

```
func turnBasedMatchmakerViewController(viewController: GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController, didFindMatch match: GKTurnBasedMatch){
    match.loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler(self.matchDataLoaded)    
    match.acceptInviteWithCompletionHandler(self.acceptInvite)
}

private func acceptInvite(match:GKTurnBasedMatch?, error:NSError?){
    guard error == nil else {
        LogUtil.log(.CRITICAL, sub: .ERROR, o: self, method: method, msg: "could not accept match invite. \(error)")
        return
    }
}
```

Player 1 after making the first turn
[image]

Player 2 before loading match from player 1
[image]

Comment: Please add the block of code where you call `acceptInviteWithCompletionHandler`

Comment: @Thunk I made edits above to include the call. I'm still stuck on this one :(

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question about entirely-programmatically-handled turn-based matches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42657539/960691), and even though the question on *this* page is about using the standard `GKTurnBasedMatchMakerViewController`, I belive the information in that post could be helpful.

What one wants, of course, is a simple delegate function named `localPlayerDidAcceptInvitation(...)`. But absent that, the information available at that link might be helpful in kludging together something that works.